# PySpark - if ID exists in Table 1 & Table 2, fill column in table 1 with TRUE else FALSE

Tags: pyspark

I am aiming to merge two tables together, on ID. Some of table 2 won't have all the ID's of table 1 and that's OK - in those cases I would like to fill a 3rd column with true or false values based on whether the IDs existed in both tables.

Let me try to articulate my problem.

Let's say I have two tables:

```
ID  TIME       ID   TIME
1   1/1/21     2    1/1/21
4   1/1/21     4    1/1/21
7   1/1/21     8    1/1/21
```

The time table is not important, what is important is ID 4. I would like to fill ID 4 with whether it exists in both tables. The final output would be like so, referencing back to table 1.

```
  ID    TIME      EXISTS_BOTH_TABLES
  1     1/1/21    FALSE
  4     1/1/21    TRUE
  7     1/1/21    FALSE
```

I realize this might be a particular type of Join, but my struggle exists also in articulating what exactly I need. I hope this helps you understand my issue.

Comment: Where does the CONVO column come from? How is it calculated?

Comment: Based on whether the ID is in both columns, to populate a new column with TRUE / FALSE

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested the following code but you should do something along these lines:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df1.join(df2, 'ID', 'left').withColumn('CONVO', when(df2.ID.isNull(), False).otherwise(True))
```

Left join on the ID and detect when the IDs don't match to fill the convo column with False, else it is true.

If you want to do both sides you could do a full join instead and detect null values for both df1.ID and df2.ID.

EDIT: I believe you've done a mistake in your example, in the result table, ID 7 should be True

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. Unfortunately I hadn't been able to get it to work.